# Normalizing an iterable type such that the output is an iterable of floats whose sum is 1

Tags: java, python, floating-point

Okay,

I've come across a rounding error problem.  I have a java program that reads a list, line-by-line, some numbers.  The program requires this list to be float (what type of float? I suspect single precision) numbers whose sum, S, is between .999 and 1.001  (i.e. .999 <= S <= 1.001).  Here is an example:

```
from numpy import array, linalg

def Normalize(X):
    NumpyX = array(X)
    Norm = linalg.norm(NumpyX)
    Normalize = NumpyX/Norm
    return Normalize

def FileMaker(FilePointer,Vector)
    for i in Vector:
        FilePointer.write('%f\n'%i)
    return


#sum(SubstitutionPoints) does not add to 1
SubstitutionPoints =[0.00606508512067950,0.00675296642376962,0.00688999694872917,0.00580692396866418,0.00680583604896024,0.00609061670962565,0.00585881991631447,0.00577148570812953,0.00600882981888663,0.00618499536435559,0.00650767341787896,0.00670521809234427,0.00699374780209504,0.00841141135948587,0.00830145870238677,0.00879477131238090,0.00918627324146331,0.00958946761973615,0.01032404247887830,0.01093417870737930,0.01188202458790520,0.01261860720648550,0.01355451051017660,0.01473818756656830,0.01623978223562570,0.01811682034513980,0.01990010225231130,0.02154250858435480,0.02418185925226890,0.02583490296173980,0.02844212438633430,0.03194935989118780,0.03534228607419560,0.03971366519834600,0.04548573525944540,0.05190994307855660,0.05190994307855660,0.05190994307855660,0.05190994307855660,0.05190994307855660,0.05190994307855660,0.05190994307855660,0.05190994307855660,0.05190994307855660,0.05190994307855660,0.05190994307855660,0.05190994307855660,0.05190994307855660,0.05190994307855660,0.05190994307855660,0.05190994307855660,0.05190994307855660,0.05190994307855660,0.05190994307855660,0.05190994307855660,0.05190994307855660,0.05190994307855660,0.05190994307855660,0.05190994307855660,0.05190994307855660,0.05190994307855660,0.05190994307855660,0.05190994307855660,0.05190994307855660,0.05190994307855660,0.05190994307855660,0.05190994307855660,0.05190994307855660,0.05190994307855660,0.05190994307855660,0.05190994307855660,0.05190994307855660,0.05190994307855660,0.05190994307855660,0.05190994307855660,0.05190994307855660,0.05190994307855660,0.05190994307855660,0.05190994307855660,0.05190994307855660,0.05190994307855660,0.05190994307855660,0.05190994307855660,0.05190994307855660,0.05190994307855660,0.05190994307855660,0.05190994307855660,0.05190994307855660,0.05190994307855660,0.05190994307855660,0.05190994307855660,0.05190994307855660,0.05190994307855660,0.05190994307855660,0.05190994307855660,0.05190994307855660,0.05190994307855660,0.05190994307855660,0.05190994307855660,0.05190994307855660,0.05190994307855660]
NormedSP = Normalize(SubstitutionPoints)
SubFile = open('Sub.txt','w')
FileMaker(SubFile,NormedSP)
SubFile.close()
```

Since python does not use single precision floats, I am worried that the file created is causing problems in my java program because my java program (metasim) returns an error:

```
Simulating files:
[BorreliaBurgdorferiB31_CP32-3.fasta]
java.lang.Exception: Substitution rates don't sum to 1.0.
!!! FAILED !!!
```

Unfortunately, I can't debug the java program because it is 'java executable'.  My only option is to give the right input.

Any suggestions/help is appreciated.

## Edit

from some suggestions of trying float32() I revised my normalize method as such:

```
def Normalize(self,X):
    Total = sum(X)
    NumpyX = array([float32(i) for i in X])
    Norm = linalg.norm(NumpyX,ord=1)
    Normalize = NumpyX/Norm
    return Normalize
```

I'm beginning to doubt that it is the single precision float problem.

Is my output being truncated and causing errors?

Comment: I don't know who keeeps deleting the answers but it is really annoying!  I do appreciate all suggestions.  it would be nice to have all of them as reference.

Comment: I would like to thank serndele (i think that was his name) for his suggestions, Daniel Pryden, and the other guy (Ivan????) for their comments

Answer (score 2):

If you just need to be accurate to three decimal places, why not just multiply the values by 1000, do all the math with integers, and only add the decimal point in the output? That way it should be easy to ensure the sum is exact.

Answer (score 1):

[`numpy.linalg.norm`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html) requires the `ord=1` keyword arg to do what you expect. Using your current data & definition...

```
>>> Normalize(substitution_points).sum()
9.0451896403987444
```

You might do this instead -- this scales negative values correctly too (`linalg.norm` sums the `abs` of the values):

```
>>> def normalize(x):
...     a = numpy.array(x)
...     return a / a.sum()
... 
>>> normalize(substitution_points).sum()
0.99999999999999789
```

`0.9999999... > 0.999`, so it *should* work, according to the spec you've offered.

But... it seems it's still not working. Try playing with `numpy.float16` -- and note that the more idiomatic way to create an array of floats is like so:

```
array([ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.], dtype=float32)
```

Comment: oops I meant to have Norm = linalg.norm(NumpyX,ord=1)

Comment: @torrho, oh. Well does that mean that simple division doesn't work for you? Or was that just a typo in your example code? (It didn't occur to me that you might be using `linalg.norm` to calculate manhattan distance.)

Comment: the typo is not the problem.  I tried using float32 as well.  I wonder if this is not the problem? perhaps something else?  any ideas

Comment: Or, if that doesn't work, then as @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams said in his deleted post, "your only real fix is to sum the normalized values, add the difference to the last element, and cross your fingers." Ignacio, you should probably undelete!

Comment: okay I will try float16. if that fails, i will try adding the difference to the first element of the vector (it's better that way for my model)

Answer (score 0):

Your Normalize method does not force the sum of the list to 1: dividing through by the norm sets the *norm* to 1. To set the total to 1, you need to divide through by the current total:

```
def normalize(X):
   total = sum(X)
   return [x/total for x in X]
```